# Can't seem to get it to write to an arrayList and then to a file

Tags: java

I have been working on this and can't seem to get it to run correctly. It should create an arraylist then add, remove, mark as loaned, mark as returned, and write to a file when you quit. I can't find what I messed up.

```
package cs1181proj1;

import static cs1181proj1.Media.media;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Veteran
 */
public class CS1181Proj1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create ArrayList and mediaFile. 

        ArrayList<Media> Item = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        File mediaFile = new File("mediaFile.dat");
        String Title;
        String Format;
        String loanedTo = null;
        String dateLoaned = null;
        int number = 0;

        if (mediaFile.exists()) {
            try {
                try (ObjectInputStream dos = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(mediaFile))) {
                    Item = (ArrayList<Media>) dos.readObject();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException a) {
                System.out.println("Thou hast erred! The file doth not exist!");
            } catch (IOException b) {
                System.out.println("GIGO My Lord or Lady!");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                System.out.println("Avast! I am in a quandry");
            }

        }
//Print out menu of choices
        while (number != 6) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1. Add new media item");
            System.out.println("2. Mark an item out on loan");
            System.out.println("3. Mark an item as Returned");
            System.out.println("4. List items in collection");
            System.out.println("5. Remove a media item");
            System.out.println("6. Quit");
            System.out.println("");

//accept users menu choice
            try {
                number = keyboard.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("That's not a number between 1 and       `        `6. IS IT!");
            }

     //Switch to tell program what method to use depending on user                 `      `//option
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    insert();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    onLoan();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    returned();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    list();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    removeItem();
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    Quit(mediaFile);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

//Method for inserting items in arraylist
    public static void insert() {
        ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("New titles name");
        Scanner newEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
        String title = newEntry.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        //title of media
        while (titleAlreadyExists(title, media)) {
            System.out.println("Title already exists");
            title = newEntry.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");

        }
        //format of media
        System.out.println("What format");
        String format = newEntry.nextLine();
        media.add(new Media(title, format));
        System.out.println("Your entry has been created.");
    }

//In case entry already exists
    public static boolean titleAlreadyExists(
            String title, ArrayList<Media> media) {
        for (Media entry : media) {
            if (entry.getTitle().equals(title)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Method for putting item on loan
    public static void onLoan() {

        System.out.println("Enter name of Title on loan");
        Scanner newLoan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();
        String loanTitle = newLoan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Who did you loan this to");
        Scanner To = new Scanner(System.in);
        String loanedTo = To.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("When was it lent out?");
        Scanner date = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dateLoaned = date.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        for (Media title : media) {

            if (title.getTitle().equals(loanTitle)) {
                title.setDateLoaned(dateLoaned);
                title.setloanedTo(loanedTo);
                System.out.println(title + " loaned to " + loanedTo + `                  `"on date" + dateLoaned + "is listed as loaned");

            }
        }
    }

    //Method for returning item in collection
    public static void returned() {

        System.out.println("Enter name of Title returned");
        Scanner returned = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();
        String returnedTitle = returned.nextLine();

        String loanedTo = null;
        String dateLoaned = null;
        System.out.println("");

        for (Media title : media) {

            if (title.getTitle().equals(returnedTitle)) {
                title.setDateLoaned(dateLoaned);
                title.setloanedTo(loanedTo);
                System.out.println(title + "is listed as returned");

            }
        }
    }

    //Method for listing items in collection
    public static void list() {
        System.out.println("Your collection contains:");
        for (int i = 0; i < media.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((media.get(i)).toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    //method for removing an item from the collection
    private static void removeItem() {
        System.out.println("What item do you want to remove?");
        Scanner remover = new Scanner(System.in);

            ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();
            String removeTitle = remover.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");

            media.stream().filter((title) -> `                                 `             (title.getTitle().equals(removeTitle))).forEach((title) -> {
                media.remove(removeTitle);
                System.out.println(title + "has been removed");
            });
        }
        //method for saving to file when the user quits the program. 
        //To ensure there is no data loss.
    public static void Quit(File mediaFile) {

        try {
            ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<>();

            try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new `    `                 FileOutputStream(mediaFile))) {
                oos.writeObject(media);
                System.out.println("Your file has been saved.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to write to file. Data not      `          `saved");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is its companion media file:

```
package cs1181proj1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 *
 * @author Veteran
 */
public class Media implements Serializable {

    static ArrayList<String> media = new ArrayList<>();

    private String Title;
    private String Format;
    private String loanedTo = null;
    private String dateLoaned = null;

    Media() {

        this.Title = ("Incorrect");
        this.Format = ("Incorrect");
        this.loanedTo = ("Available");
        this.dateLoaned = ("Available");

    }

    Media(String Title, String Format) {

        this.Title = Title;
        this.Format = Format;
        this.loanedTo = ("Available");
        this.dateLoaned = ("Available");

    }

    //Get and Set Title

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    //Get and Set Format

    public String getFormat() {
        return this.Format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String Format) {
        this.Format = Format;
    }

    //Get and Set loanedTo
    public String getLoanedTo() {
        return this.loanedTo;
    }

    public void setloanedTo (String loanedTo){
        this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
    }

    //Get and set dateLoaned
    public String getDateLoaned() {
        return this.dateLoaned;
    }

    public void setDateLoaned(String dateLoaned){
        this.dateLoaned = dateLoaned;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){

        return this.Title + ", " + this.Format +", " + this.loanedTo + ", " 
                + this.dateLoaned;

    }

    public static Comparator <Media> TitleComparator = new Comparator <Media>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Media t, Media t1) {

        String title = t.getTitle().toUpperCase();
        String title1 = t1.getTitle().toUpperCase();

        return title.compareTo(title1);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Which case number (1-6) doesn't work? And please explain the actual and expected behavior for that case.

Comment: It seems like none are working correctly. 1 should add an item to the array.2 should alter an entry to show as loaned out with the name of the person loaned to. 3 should return change an entry to remove the name and date item was loaned. 4. should print out the list. 5 should remove an item from the arraylist. 6. should save the arraylist to a file, and end the program. it seems like its working till you try to print out the file.  but all it prints is "Your collection contains:" and nothing else.

Comment: Oh, it does quit properly when I choose 6. I just can't find the file. I wrote this in NetBeans. (school requires its use). I am also very new to Java. Although I think you can tell.

Comment: The file is created in current user directory. You can get the full path by printing `mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()`.